# Extraer datos de la BD en columnas de tres

Tags: php, html, sql

necesito ayuda para colocar los datos traídos de una base de datos en una tabla HTML.

Tengo este código:

```
<div class="card-block">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT idEmpresa,nombreComercial FROM empresas";
        $objetoBBDD->consultarBD($sql);

        while($fila = $objetoBBDD->devolverFilas())
        {
            echo'<table style="width: 100%;">';
                echo'<tr>';
                    echo'<td><input type="hidden" name="idFormacion" value="'.$fila["idEmpresa"].'"></td>';
                echo'</tr>';
                echo'<tr>';
                    echo'<td><label><b>Empresa</b></label></td>';
                echo'</tr>';
                echo'<tr>';
                    echo'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">'.$fila["nombreComercial"].'</button>';
                echo'</tr>';
            echo'</table>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

El resultado de eso es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero lo que quiero saber es como hacerlo en 4 columnas con 3 empresas cada columna.

Como lo tengo ahora todas las empresas se ponen una debajo de otra.

El resultado esperado seria algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si deseas que sea algo dinamico (N columnas dependiendo del ancho de la pantalla), podrias usar las librerias [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) o [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html). Si deseas algo estatico (siempre 4 columnas), deberia ser tan simple como utilizar dos ciclos =) Cual es la que te interesa?

Comment: Ahora que lo dices será mejor dinámico, porque no siempre tendré cuatro columnas

Comment: @cavpollo cómo puedo hacerlo de forma dinámica con boostrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasos para tener columnas dinamicas con Bootstrap:

1. Incluir la libreria. Esto lo puedes conseguir descargando el css de bootstrap, o referenciandolo directamente a un sitio donde se encuentra alojado.

Siguiendo el [Getting Started de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

2. En vez de usar tablas debes utilizar `div` de manera anidada (es solo un ejemplo):

`<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 1 Columna 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 1 Columna 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 1 Columna 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 2 Columna 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 2 Columna 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Fila 2 Columna 3</div>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>`

2.1 Necesitas un *div* que vaya a contener tu *tabla*, con la clase `container`.

2.2 Agrega un *div* con la clase *row* por cada fila que quieres que tenga tu tabla.

2.3 Agrega un *div* dentro del *row* para cada una de las columnas que deseas.

Por default, bootstrap trabaja con 12 unidades de columnas. Entonces el valor que se use como clase de columna, define que tantas de esas 12 unidades ocupa.

2.3.1 A tu div columna colocale la clase `col-4` para que por default se muestren 3 columnas  (12 / 3 = 4 columnas).

2.3.2 Colocale la clase `col-sm-6` a todas tus columnas, para que en un ancho de pequeño (de 576px a 768px), se muestren 2 columnas (12 / 6 = 2 columnas).

Al final deberias tener algo como esto (Asumo que quieres que todas las columnas sean del mismo ancho, que normalmente se muestren 4, y cuando la pantalla sea pequeña se muestren 2) :

`<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 1 Columna 1</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 1 Columna 2</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 1 Columna 3</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 2 Columna 1</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 2 Columna 2</div>
        <div class="col-3 col-sm-6">Fila 2 Columna 3</div>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>`

Dependiendo del comportamiento que quieras que tenga la tabla, seran las clases y estructura de html que deberas utilizar. Puedes leer mas al respecto [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).